# VB : Parentheses automatically added in error

Tags: vb.net, parentheses

My colleagues frown upon me because according to our sourcesafe, I added parentheses to the method-property thus resulting in a stackoverflow.
Since I'm sure I did no such thing on purpose, I wonder if somehow I used a obscure shortcut which performed these changes.

This kind of stuff :

```
Public Function Opslaan() As Boolean
    If something_wrong() Then
        opslaan = False
    End If
    If opslaan = False Then
        Do_Something_Else()
    End If 
    Return opslaan
End Function
```

and this got changed into :

```
Public Function Opslaan() As Boolean
    If something_wrong() Then
        opslaan = False
    End If
    If opslaan() = False Then  '' See the parentheses here added automatically
        Do_Something_Else()
    end If 

    Return opslaan
End Function
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that it was changed to: `if something wrong`, where is the underscore? Also, where is the variable `opslaan`? The method has the same name so i guess that Visual Studio thinks that you want to call it. Please don't use this VB6 syntax anymore(`opslaan = false` means the same as `Return false`).

Comment: I prefer to use following logic (as it is also like that in C#): calling a function or method -> add parentheses (even without parameters), calling a property -> no parentheses. However, if your coding standards say you should not add parentheses to a method call without functions, you should oblige.

Comment: Tim : you are right, this is old VB6 code which still resides in some code blocks. The variable opslaan is not declared due to the reason you already mentioned. I elaborated this in a comment on JoelC's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like bad old VB6 code converted to VB.NET.

The problem is VB6 allowed you to treat the current function name as a variable and update its value all throughout the method. Then, when you exited the method whatever value this variable had would be returned to the caller. This syntax is confusing and should never be used, even in VB6 since there is a better way.

Update all code you find like this to something like:

```
Public Function Opslaan() As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = True

    If something_wrong() Then
        result = False
    end if
    If result = False Then
         Do_Something_Else()
    End If 

    Return result 
End Function
```

This is much clearer code and will never mistakenly call the same routine.

Also, this is **totally personal preference**, but I prefer to not check booleans with equals statements. So `If result = False Then` becomes `If Not result Then` and `If result = true Then` becomes `If result Then`. That almost always feels cleaner to me for Booleans.

Comment: Thanks JoelC, but it is indeed an 'old' vb6 project which is being upgraded to a 3-tier model.
I completely agree that this syntax is simply not done, but there you go, that's legacy for you I think.

So apart from the justly comments, I simply wanted to know if something could have added those parentheses unwillingly ?
I hate the idea that code can be changed without me changing it ;-)

Comment: @ChrisO. Nevertheless, my comments mostly stand. The compiler is automatically adding the brackets to try and "help" you use the correct syntax when calling your function. Since the only thing defined in this scope with that name is the function. Stop using the function name as a variable to handle your return value and your problem will go away.

Comment: To simplify my above comment: yes it is likely the IDE has added the brackets automatically and it wasn't you.